# MongoDB invalid character 'ÿ' looking for beginning of value

Tags: json, database, mongodb, object

I am trying to add a database into mongodb atlas but the an error persist throughout all my json files. T

Full error message:

> 2023-10-22T16:48:08.867+0800 Failed: error processing
> document #1: invalid character 'ÿ' looking for beginning of value

inside my json file

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"652b9a3d332f7cee65d16731"},"Title":"Saving Private Ryan","Description":"Saving Private Ryan is a 1998 American war film directed by Steven Spielberg...","Genre":{"Name":"War","Description":"War films depict the experiences of war, including its effects on society..."},"Director":{"Name":"Steven Spielberg","Bio":"Steven Spielberg is an American filmmaker known for his exceptional work in war and action genres..."},"Actors":["Tom Hanks","Matt Damon","Tom Sizemore","Edward Burns","Barry Pepper"],"Featured":true}
{"_id":{"$oid":"652bae24332f7cee65d16737"},"Title":"Babylon","Description":"Description for Babylon movie","Genre":{"Name":"Drama","Description":"Description for Drama genre"},"Director":{"Name":"Damien Chazelle","Bio":"Damien Chazelle is an American director known for his exceptional work in drama and musical genres. Born in 1985, he has received critical acclaim for his contributions to the film industry."},"Actors":["Margot Robbie","Bradd Pitt","Tobey Maguire"],"Featured":true}
{"_id":{"$oid":"652bae24332f7cee65d16738"},"Title":"Dunkirk","Description":"Description for Dunkirk movie","Genre":{"Name":"War","Description":"Description for War genre"},"Director":{"Name":"Christopher Nolan","Bio":"Christopher Nolan is a British-American filmmaker known for his remarkable achievements in war and action genres. Born in 1970, he has left a significant impact on cinema."},"Actors":["Harry Styles","Cillian Murphy","Tom Hardy","Mark Rylance"],"Featured":true}
{"_id":{"$oid":"652bae24332f7cee65d16739"},"Title":"Waterloo","Description":"Description for Waterloo movie","Genre":{"Name":"War","Description":"Description for War genre"},"Director":{"Name":"Sergey Bondarchuk","Bio":"Sergey Bondarchuk was a Soviet actor and filmmaker who made significant contributions to war and drama genres. Born in 1920, he is remembered for his impactful work in cinema."},"Actors":["Rod Steiger","Christopher Plummer","Orson Welles"],"Featured":false}
{"_id":{"$oid":"652bae24332f7cee65d1673a"},"Title":"Citizen Kane","Description":"Description for Citizen Kane movie","Genre":{"Name":"Drama","Description":"Description for Drama genre"},"Director":{"Name":"Orson Welles","Bio":"Orson Welles was an American actor and director renowned for his work in drama and mystery genres. Born in 1915, he left a lasting legacy in the world of cinema."},"Actors":["Orson Welles","Joseph Cotten","Dorothy Comingore","Everett Sloane"],"Featured":true}
{"_id":{"$oid":"652bae24332f7cee65d1673b"},"Title":"All Quiet on the Western Front","Description":"Description for All Quiet on the Western Front movie","Genre":{"Name":"War","Description":"Description for War genre"},"Director":{"Name":"Edward Berger","Bio":"Edward Berger is a German director known for his contributions to war and drama genres. Born in 1970, his work has been critically acclaimed."},"Actors":["Felix Kammerer","Daniel"],"Featured":true}
```

Comment: What exactly does the full error message say? What is in the rest of your json files?